# Using coords2country function in R on Exclusive Economic Zones not Country boundaries

Tags: r, maps, latitude-longitude, country-codes, coords

I want to assign country Exclusive Economic Zones to point data from a raster where the points represent Aragonite saturation levels in the ocean. 
The raster is a single layer that gives an Aragonite value for many latitude/longitude points in the ocean.
I want to assign each latitude/longitude point to an exclusive economic zone.
[This site](http://marineregions.org/eezsearch.php) does it for single pairs of coordinates but I have 15,000 points so I am hoping it is possible to do in R.

The data look like this:

```
      long      lat Aragonite
1 20.89833 84.66917  1.542071
2 22.69496 84.66917  1.538187
3 24.49159 84.66917  1.537830
4 26.28822 84.66917  1.534834
5 28.08485 84.66917  1.534595
6 29.88148 84.66917  1.532505
```

Previously I have used the below code to assign countries to raster points but this gives NA back for many of the points in the ocean that are within national EEZ's.

```
#convert the raster to points for assigning countries
r.pts <- rasterToPoints(r, spatial = TRUE)

#view new proj 4 string of spatialpointsdataframe
proj4string(r.pts)
##[1] "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0"

###converting reclassified points to countries
# The single argument to this function, points, is a data.frame in which:
#   - column 1 contains the longitude in degrees
#   - column 2 contains the latitude in degrees
coords2country = function(r.pts)
{
countriesSP <- getMap(resolution='high')
#countriesSP <- getMap(resolution='high') #you could use high res map from rworldxtra if you were concerned about detail

#setting CRS directly to that from rworldmap
r.pts = SpatialPoints(r.pts, proj4string=CRS(proj4string(countriesSP))) 

# use 'over' to get indices of the Polygons object containing each point 
indices = over(r.pts, countriesSP)
# return the ADMIN names of each country
indices$ADMIN 
#indices$ISO3 # returns the ISO3 code
#indices$continent   # returns the continent (6 continent model)
#indices$REGION   # returns the continent (7 continent model)
}

#get country names for each pair of points
rCountries <- coords2country(r.pts)
```

Is there any way to do a similar function to coords2countries but for EEZ's in the ocean?

EDIT: some data for reproducible example

```
dput(head(r.pts))
structure(list(layer = c(5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5), x = c(-178.311660375408,-176.511660375408, -174.711660375408, -172.911660375408, -171.111660375408,-169.311660375408), y = c(73.1088933113454, 73.1088933113454,73.1088933113454, 73.1088933113454, 73.1088933113454, 73.1088933113454),.Names = c("layer", "x", "y"),row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Please provide a `dput()` of sample data for reproducibility

Comment: Sorry, i have done so above with a subset of the data.

Answer (score 0):

You need a shapefile that includes the EEZs. Download the one that is here: World EEZ v9 (2016-10-21, 123 MB) http://www.marineregions.org/downloads.php#marbound

You can load the EEZ shapefile with the `readOGR()` function from the `rgdal` package. Unzip the EEZ shapefile zip to your working directory and run `countriesSP <- rgdal::readOGR(dsn = ".", layer = "eez_boundaries")` in place of `countriesSP <- getMap(resolution='high')`

None of the example data you provided falls in a country's EEZ, so I can't tell if this actually works, but it probably should...

```
library(sp)
library(rworldmap)
library(rgeos)

r <- read.table(header = TRUE, text = "
long lat Aragonite
1 20.89833 84.66917  1.542071
2 22.69496 84.66917  1.538187
3 24.49159 84.66917  1.537830
4 26.28822 84.66917  1.534834
5 28.08485 84.66917  1.534595
6 29.88148 84.66917  1.532505
")
# or
#r <- data.frame(long = c(-178.311660375408,-176.511660375408, -174.711660375408, -172.911660375408, -171.111660375408,-169.311660375408), 
#                lat = c(73.1088933113454, 73.1088933113454,73.1088933113454, 73.1088933113454, 73.1088933113454, 73.1088933113454))

r.pts <- sp::SpatialPoints(r)

# download file from here: http://www.marineregions.org/download_file.php?fn=v9_20161021
# put the zip file in your working directory: getwd()
unzip('World_EEZ_v9_20161021.zip')

# countriesSP <- rworldmap::getMap(resolution = "high")
# or
countriesSP <- rgdal::readOGR(dsn = ".", layer = "eez_boundaries")

r.pts <- sp::SpatialPoints(r.pts, proj4string = sp::CRS(proj4string(countriesSP))) 
indices <- over(r.pts, countriesSP)
indices$ADMIN
```